# Hiding Textbox in SSRS and freeing up space

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, header, ssrs-2008-r2

I am designing a report using **SSRS 2008 R2** where there can be 2-3 sub headers. Now the headers are passed as parameters showing different options such as date range etc.Now I have used three TextBoxes for the three headers but the problem is if I pass 2 headers and even if the third `TextBox` is hidden it takes up space. I would have used a `tablix` had the headers appeared in a body section but It seems I cannot use a `tablix` in the header section.
I hope I was able to make myself clear. Does anyone have any answers regarding this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I may make a suggestion, that I've used before, use *placeholders*.  So, what you do is go into the box that is right before the optional text box.  Then, right click.  You should see an option at the bottom for Create Placeholder.  Click that and it will ask you to create an expression.  Do an IIF check on your variable.

Example: `IIF(MyVar = 1, vbcrlf + "My Header", "")`

What this will do is check to see if `MyVar = 1`.  If it does, then it appends onto your text box a new line with the text "My Header".  Otherwise, it will take up no space.

Please let me know if this helps and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to 'play' with 3 properties of your `TextBoxes`.

- `CanGrow`: True
- `CanShrink`: True
- `Hidden`: `=IIf(Parameters!YourParameter.Value = "", True, False)`

To save space, you can also set a minimum `Height` for your `TextBoxes` and put them attached to each other.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the visiblity:

1)select textbox
2)right click on text box.
3) go to Text Box Properties
4)visiblity tab>click on "fx" for expression and write following code.

use if condition:

```
=IIF(Cstr(Header.value))="",TRUE,FALSE)
```

i hope it will solve ur issue.

Comment: Hi, Manoj the problem is even if i hide the textboxes it still takes up space i am looking for a way such that the hidden text boxes dont take up spaces. I used expression in a single textbox with separating the parameters with adding vbcrlf but the header area does not render properly in pdfs. 

I used table in the body area that solves it but i cannot repeat the table on all pages.